# How to remove duplicate tuples using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows

```
Col1  Col2
12    34
34    12
```

Considering, these are duplicates how we delete them?
I tried solving this question using self joins. But I am not able to get the required answer. Can someone help?

Comment: So your condition for duplicates is that the two columns are interchangeable?

Comment: Yes. They have the same meaning if they are in either column.

Comment: You have to consider both the columns to heck duplicates

Comment: Any particular RDBMS (MySQL/Oracle/...)?

Comment: I am working in MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) and [LEAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) to 'order' your columns, and then use distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GREATEST(col1, col2) as first, LEAST(col1, col2) as second from yourTable
```

This will give you a distinct result. If what you're looking for is delete, you can delete everything not in this result:

```
DELETE FROM yourTable where (col1, col2) NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT GREATEST(col1, col2) as first, LEAST(col1, col2) as second from yourTable
)
```

Comment: Will it work if I have non-duplicate tuples too in the same table?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to have a symmetric relation: for example, if A is a friend of B, then B is also a friend of A? I also assume that both columns are foreign IDs, and numeric. If this is not so, you will have to adapt.

The best way is to never ever insert the two versions at all; normalise the relation so that the smaller one is always in Col1, and larger one always in Col2. I.e. for `13 -> 27` you would insert `[13, 27]`; for `27 -> 13`, you would again insert `[13, 27]`, if it wasn't present again.

If you already have a messed up table, I'd probably just do:

```
UPDATE IGNORE t
SET col1=(@temp:=col1), col1 = col2, col2 = @temp
WHERE col1 > col2;
```

to normalise it (didn't try, could have errors; also, MySQL syntax, you'd probably have to adapt for other engines); then this to remove the extras in case both directions existed:

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE col1 > col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL syntax:

```
DELETE b 
FROM mytable a, mytable b 
WHERE a.col1 = b.col2 AND a.col2 = b.col1 AND a.col1 > b.col2;
```

It doesn't work if the two values are identical, but you have a unique constraint to prevent duplicates in that case, right?